# How can I combine these two regex expressions? (Words with and without apostrophes)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a regex to capture every word in a string (including apostrophe) such as the following:

```
Despite trying and trying I haven't found a regex to capture all these words
```

I do however want it to ignore words like `'''`, and read `word` from `words'`, and `cause` from `'cause`; i.e. the apostrophe must be within the text.

I have the following two expressions:

```
[a-z]+'[a-z]+
[a-z]+
```

I am assuming they can be joined by a simple operator, but I can't find out what that operator might be.

Comment: Use optional quantifier: `[a-z]+(?:'[a-z]+)?`

Comment: What is your regex tool/language?

Comment: you actually mean that when reading input `words'` it output just `word`, without the final `s` ???

Answer (score 2):

In Python you can use this alternation based regex to match all words with single quote inside and ignore `'word1 word2'` words:

```
s = r"Despite trying and trying I haven't found a regex to capture all these words 'but not capturing these'"

print filter(None, re.findall(r"'[^']*'|(\b\w+(?:'\w+)?\b)", s))
//=> ['Despite', 'trying', 'and', 'trying', 'I', "haven't", 'found', 'a', 'regex', 'to', 'capture', 'all', 'these', 'words']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aH1gM8/2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(\w+'\w+)|(\w+)
```

The above still includes `words'` and `'cause` but without the apostrophe.

Comment: This is what my research turned up, but it doesn't appear to work when I try it out on regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

This regex will catch all words that can optionally contain (even multiple) `'` inside them, but not starting or ending with `'`

```
(\w[\w']+\w|\w+)
```

See [a demo here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gtoLO2WsICBto0Ng)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

Using a group and "?" is elegant and should be the fastest implementation.  The following expression is not limited to python but works in any tool that accepts *Extended Regular Expressions*.  I am also not sure what you want to do with numbers (another reason "\w" is not used in the answer):

### [A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)?

```
$ str="Despite trying and trying I haven't found a regex to capture all these words... 'cause"
$ echo "$str" | sed -r "s/[A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)?/MATCH/g"
MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH... 'MATCH
$ echo "$str" | awk "{ gsub(/[A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)?/,\"MATCH\") } 1"
MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH MATCH... 'MATCH
```

Here is the nice diagram from www.debuggex.com ...

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/eNXI5_NqpOMRP6AY)

The Basic Regular Expression adds a couple \'s:

### [A-Za-z]\+\('[A-Za-z]\+\)\?

If you have POSIX character classes:

EXTENDED:

### [[:alpha:]]+('[[:alpha:]]+)?

BASIC:

### [[:alpha:]]\+\('[[:alpha:]]\+\)\?